# ImageButton show nothing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imagebutton

I have `RecyclerView` include `ImageButton` play each item. But when I run `ImageButton` show nothing.

https://gist.github.com/tugnt/98917e0a2293d6cddd2e0e6e21d3d4fb

Comment: can you please put your java code?because issue is in your java code not xml.

Comment: @dipali This my RecyclerAdapter https://gist.github.com/tungnguyentrong/465688f8bc98e6e3088d00590327dae7

Comment: But ImageButton is show nothing. I can't click it and can't  handle imageButton click event ??

Comment: please replace this code.
 holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
Log.i("click imageview,"click");
            }
        });

Comment: I don't understand what you said. Because , Icon of ImageView is show nothing, I can't handle event imageButton click and event setOnClickListener never run ??

Comment: you can see it : https://postimg.org/image/vp20f7vq9/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
        android:src="@drawable/ic_speaker"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/pd_3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your xml,see `android:src` property is not for button. It's imageview property. So use `ImageView` instead of `Button` or set `android:background` for `Button`

```
 <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_speaker"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/pd_3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now try this.

Comment: It not working. I try with text button but show nothing in recyclerView.

Comment: plz try imageview.

Comment: @dipali bijo issue hase. Imageview no nai hoy

Comment: @Piyush its issue for not showing image in list adapter.so its probably its imageview issue

Comment: pan enu alignment proper na hoy to pan bani sake ne

Comment: I try with `ImaveView` , `ImageButton` but show nothing.

Comment: check this..http://prnt.sc/cy6a6p
i am using Imageview and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below is your code, in this you have used the  **android:src="@drawable/ic_speaker"** for the button.

```
<Button
            android:src="@drawable/ic_speaker"
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/pd_3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But **src** is for imageview, which doesn't support the button view. So use background instead of src and in the xml preview you cannot see the play button. Have a look at the below code, I have edited the code

```
<Button
            android:background="@drawable/ic_speaker"
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/pd_3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Use the xml preview to see whether you can see the view or not, which helps to sort put the bug easily and save our time. Hope this is helpful :)